# How do i store a value in my txt file without it disappearing

Tags: python

```
import tkinter as tk
```

#The data does appear in the txt file. but after pressing the submitting button it doesnt stay there.

```
def submit():
     outfile = open("text.txt", "w")
     A = entry1.get()
     B = entry2.get()
     username = "UserName, "
     password = "Password, "
     C = username + A
     D = password + B
     outfile.write(C + " " + D)
     entry1.delete(0, tk.END)
     entry2.delete(0, tk.END)
```

#If i put a input and submit it will just be thr and not stored. how do i store the value in the txt file permently without it going away? Must i do a loop?

```
frame = tk.Tk()

tk.Label(text="Username").grid(row=1)
tk.Label(text="Password").grid(row=2)



entry1 = tk.Entry()
entry2 = tk.Entry()

entry1.grid(row=1 , column=1)
entry2.grid(row=2 , column=1)

tk.Button(frame, text="Submit" , command=submit).grid(row=3,column=0, pady=4)


frame.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong. The correct way to write to a file is:

```
outfile.write(C + " " + D)
```

Answer (score 0):

file.write is a function, not a variable.
So this

```
outfile.write = (C + " " + D)
```

should be

```
outfile.write(C + " " + D)
```

At the end, don't forget to close the file. Otherwise, it might not be saved.